# Dot Net Core 2.0 multiple cookies

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am trying to migrate a website to core 2.0. There are multiple cookies, of the form,

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "cookieA",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
    AutomaticChallenge = false
});
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "cookieB",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = false,
    AutomaticChallenge = false
});
```

These cookies are used to track where the user is in the sign-in process. I see that in core 2.0, this process is changed, and moved to the services pipeline, but I'm not clear on how to create multiple cookies, as well as how to translate these settings. Further, I'm using identity server 4 and need all of its requisite cookies to be unmodified. This wasn't a problem in the previous version, but looks like it may be an issue here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add multiple cookie authentication to your services

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie("CookieA", optionA =>
            {
                // config cookieA
            })
            .AddCookie("CookieB", optionB =>
            {
                // config cookieB
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how to convert the AutomaticAuthenticate and Automatic challenge flags for each cookie. All but one of the cookies have these set to false, but one is set to true.